# Regarding units modulo $n$

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

I'm working through a lecture video on abstract algebra where the lecturer points out that an element $\overline{a} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is invertible if and only if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. I'm fine with this fact, but typically every time I've proved it, I take the simplest representative of the equivalence class, i.e., an element of $\{0,1, \ldots, n-1\}$. He commented that this is true for any representative of the class. I'm not fully certain I understand why.

Trying to reformulate the claim: if $a \equiv b \pmod n$ and $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, then $\gcd(b,n) = 1$.

After checking around for some properties of the $\gcd$, I came across:
$$
\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a + mb, b)
$$
for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. This appears useful. As $a \equiv b \pmod n$, there exists $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a - b = nt$, hence $a = b + nt$. By the above result, we have
$$
\gcd(a,n) = \gcd(b + nt, n) = \gcd(b,n),
$$
so $\gcd(b,n) = 1$.

Is this argument sound?

Comment: Looks good from here.

Comment: Yes indeed. By the way, proving that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a+mb,b)$ is a very good exercise in using the definitions.

Comment: You actually proved the stronger useful statement: If $a\equiv b \pmod n$ then $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)$.